# How to archive using the shell extension and still exclude files with 7zip?

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

How can I exclude files from archiving in 7-zip's "Add to Archive" dialogue? I know how to do this from the command line, but it doesn't seem possible from the "Add to Archive" dialogue.

I thought the Parameters edit box would do it, but it didn't work (see screenshot). Looking at the help, it says that it is for specifying parameters for compression. If it is exclusively for compression parameters, it should **say** *Compression Parameters*. :(

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the edits and embedding the screen shot everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the Parameters field only seems to accept compression (-m) related params. The misleading text is just bad UI.  Perhaps the developer hoped one day to add support for all the other command-line switches, but confused users have been requesting this on the forum since 2005 or even earlier and I see no change till date.